# No se actualiza la información en los componentes hijos. React

Tags: reactjs, props, componentes

Muy buenas, estoy desarrollando unas gráficas en la cual manejo 2 componentes en jerarquía.
Uno se llama `<GraficosIn/>` otro `<Grafico/>` donde renderiza la data.
Muestro el padre:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import config from '../resources/config/config'


import Grafico from '../components/graficos/Grafico'

const GraficosIn = ({ }) => {

  const [sqlMes, setSqlMes] = useState("SELECT ventas.name, ventas.value FROM ventas WHERE camp = 'in'")

  const [dataGeneralMes, setDataGeneralMes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dataGeneralMes.length == 0 && dataGeneralMes.length == 0 ? loadDataMes() : ''
    setInterval(loadData, 30000);
  }, [])

  // ------------------------------- Mes ------------------------------------
  const loadDataMes = async () => {
    var res = await axios.get(`${config.urlServer}/server/getData/${sqlMes}`)
    setDataGeneralMes(res.data)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
        <Grafico
          data={dataGeneralMes}
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default GraficosIn;
```

Lo tengo programado para que cada 30 segundos se me actualice el grafico. El componente del gráfico recibe la data y muestra valores, sin mas procesos. Lo cierto es que me actualiza la dataGeneralMes como lo espero pero el componente de Gráfico como ya cargó inicialmente, no actualiza; es más se queda con la data inicial que está en blanco, omitiendo las consultas realizadas en el useEffect.
Una solución que encontré fue eperar a que tuviera datos.

```
<div className="container-fluid" >
  {dataGeneralMes.length > 0
    ? <Grafico
        dataGeneralMes={ dataGeneralMes }
      /> 
      : null 
  }
</div>
```

Claro me carga la data inicial pero no se actualiza como lo espero. Un saludo.
Agrego componente `<Grafico/>`: Ahora corregido.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { ResponsiveContainer, PieChart, Pie, Legend, Cell, Tooltip } from 'recharts';

const COLORS = ["#17A606", "#A60606", "#a2a2a2", "#FFE20C"];

const Grafico = ({ data }) => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
  }, [data])

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: 300 }}>
      <ResponsiveContainer>
        <PieChart>
          <Legend />
          <Tooltip />
          <Pie dataKey="value"
            data={data}
            fill="#8884d8"
            label >

            {data.map((entry, index) => (
              <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />
            ))}
          </Pie>
        </PieChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Grafico;
```

Eso es todo, con eso se resuelve el problema, re-enderizando el componente hijo cada vez que los datos en el componente padre cambien. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías intentar pasarle un segundo argumento con el estado `dataGeneralMes`  a la función `useEffect()` para decirle a React que debe re-redenrizar el componente por cada vez que escuche cambios en ese estado.

Eso es lo que recomienda la [documentación oficial de React](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

Así que haciendo eso el `useEffect()` te quedaría así:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    loadDataMes();
    setInterval(loadDataMes, 30000);
  }, [dataGeneralMes])
```

Comment: Bien, pero en el server se queda consultando continuamente

Comment: Además con el setInterval ya le defino que consulte cada 30 segundos, lo que no me actualiza es la data que paso al grafico, para que vuelva a mostrar los datos actuales

Comment: Y si establezco una variable par que cada vez que cambie el estado desmonto y vuelvo a mostrar el Componente <Grafico/>. Para que se actualice en el setInterval

Comment: No termino de entender cuál es el problema de mi respuesta. Lo que te propongo es que se re-renderice el componente por cada vez que se mute el estado `dataGeneralMes`. Hacer eso, como consecuencia, hará que la prop `data` que le pasas al componente  `<Grafico />` sea actualizada y le pase los datos correctos. De todas formas y para tener más información de tu problema, sería bueno que nos muestres el contenido de tu componente `<Grafico />` para tener un panorama más completo.

Comment: Bueno, tuve que incorporar una validación en el useEffect. La dejo abajo del todo

Comment: sin embargo después de un lapso de tiempo vuelve a consultar el server continuamente

Comment: Muy mala practica intergrar una funcion asincrona en el hooks de react `useEffect`

Comment: @Samuel Sobalvarro considerando que lo que estoy sugiriendo integrar al `useEffect`  no es la función asíncrona en sí (la función `loadDataMes`) si no más bien el estado que resulta afectado en dicha función (el estado `dataGeneralMes`), entonces ¿por qué se consideraría eso una mala práctica? Me gustaría que fundamentes tu respuesta y nos proveas enlaces que nos ayuden a comprender mejor ese punto.

Comment: Viendo que efectivamente el componente se re-enderiza en el effect (así como lo expuso el colega – Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza, no tuve la necesidad de volver a reenderizar el componente padre, sin embargo el componente hijo se le aplicó un useEffect para que cada vez que cambie la variable de los datos alojada en el componente padre y pasada como props al componente hijo, se re-enderiza. Dejo todo el resultado en la pregunta para que lo puedas observar y verificar. Gracias a todos los que participaron en el foro.